# Adding progress bar to file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a simple progress bar to this html with jquery, what is the most minimalistic way to do so? I just need a percent value and a progress bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="basic.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you already considered and/or tried?

Comment: I have found a lot of plugins but all of them seemed to be complex and not working at all. I can see the upload status at the left corner of my browser so I thought there would be an easy way to display this value.

Comment: Have a look at this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777837/progress-bar-for-file-uploads-to-php-using-ajax-and-bootstrap/46788037#46788037

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a project which I was supposed to do the samething. As you probably did, I went through lots of plugins and I found `dmUploader` plugin particularly useful. It allows you fetching the image by drag and drop as well as `input` tag. The plugin is available [**HERE**](https://github.com/danielm/uploader).

I have created a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/MKXVrN), which I think is the best way to learn how to use this plugin. As you might notice, lines of jQuery code from 1 through 290 are just the plugin itself. I had to paste it there since the plugin does not have CDN link. Let's go through the codes:

**HTML**

```
<div class="SciSecPic">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-picture-o"></i>
    <label>
        <span>Click to browse your picture</span>
        <input type="file" title='Click to add Files' style="display:none;">
    </label>

    <div class="progress" style=" display:none;">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
  0%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need a container div, called `SciSecPic` in this example, a `label` which contains `span` and `input` tags inside. Remember the `input` is hidden and your button is your `span` tag. This is just how this plugin works. Then you can have your progress bar, div with `progress` class, which in this case is a **Bootstrap** progress bar. It primarily is not displayed and only will be shown when uploading is in progress.

There is no special setting required for **CSS** so I will skip that part and refer you to the working example.

**jQuery - Setting dmUploader**

```
var readPic;

$(".SciSecPic").each(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    self.dmUploader({
        //url: "/Something/ImageSaver",
        url: "http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=ali",
        dataType: "json",
        allowedTypes: "image/*",
        //extraData: {
            //Name: self.data("name"),
            //Id: ~~self.data("id")
        //},
        onInit: function () {

        },
        onNewFile: function (id, file) {

            // showing progressbar
            $(this).find(".progress").show(200);

            /* preparing image for preview */
            if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    readPic = e.target.result;
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            };

        },
        onUploadProgress: function (id, percent) {
            $(this).find(".progress-bar").width(percent + "%").attr("aria-valuenow", percent).text(percent + "%");
        },
        onComplete: function () {

            var thisEl = $(this);

            addPic(thisEl, readPic);

            // to fadeout and reset the progress bar at the end
            setTimeout(function () {
                thisEl.find(".progress").hide(200, function () {
                    thisEl.find(".progress-bar").width("0%").attr("aria-valuenow", 0).text("0%");
                })
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

The variable is just a placeholder to store dataURL of the image to show later, when uploading is completed. What necessarily is happening that you have to change `url` to the `.php` file in PHP or controller if you use MVC. You also can add extra data using `extraData` method. `dmUploader` provides you with different callback functions. They are very much self explanatory. For instance, `onUploadProgress` is where you can get the upload percentage and show it in the progress bar, `onNewFile` is where you can show your progress bar and to read the image in dataURL format to show it on the go in your HTML markup, and most importantly `onComplete` where you can do whatever you want after upload is finished. This is where I called `addPic` function that I wrote to show the uploaded picture on top of the input box.

To keep this answer short, I will not explain or copy `addPic` function here. IT is very simple to understand by the way. That's pretty much it. Now you can have your dmUploader.